# SteamCMD authenticate with API Key

Tags: github-actions, steam, steamworks-api

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that automatically pushes my game to steam:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3.3.0

  - name: Download build directories
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: game-builds

  - name: Setup steamcmd
    run: |
      mkdir -p $HOME/steamcmd
      cd $HOME/steamcmd
      curl -sqL "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz" | tar zxvf -

  - name: Upload to Steam
    run: |
      $HOME/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh +login ${{ secrets.STEAM_USERNAME }} ${{ secrets.STEAM_PASSWORD }} +run_app_build_http ./steam_deploy/lin_deploy.vdf +quit
      $HOME/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh +login ${{ secrets.STEAM_USERNAME }} ${{ secrets.STEAM_PASSWORD }} +run_app_build_http ./steam_deploy/win_deploy.vdf +quit
```

The problem I have is this workflow fails cause the computer (which will always change) is not allowed. GitHub spins up a new container when it runs each build.

here is the error:

```
Logging in user '***' to Steam Public...
This computer has not been authenticated for your account using Steam Guard.
Please check your email for the message from Steam, and enter the Steam Guard
 code from that message.
You can also enter this code at any time using 'set_steam_guard_code'
 at the console.
Steam Guard code:FAILED (Account Logon Denied)
Error: Process completed with exit code 5.
```

I would like to use the `Web API` key to deploy. This would help for future builds.

How would API key auth look in a GitHub Actions workflow for steamcmd?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why the "Github Actions" section was removed from the title. It's an integral part of the question.

Comment: That information is already in the tags, and doesn't need to be repeated in the title. [ask] summarizes that as "Don't include tags in the title".